# SauceLabs Pass/Fail using phpunit

Tags: phpunit, saucelabs

How do i mark the test pass/fail in saucelabs? I have my test cases written in PHPunit. Right now all the test cases are marked "finished"

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you have already read through the [SauceLabs PHP tutorial](https://docs.saucelabs.com/tutorials/php/)?

You have to setup a process/method to report the status of a job back to SauceLabs as 'passed' in case of no failures. Essentially when you start your test, you have to use SauceLabs API to get the job ID that is executing the current test. After successful completion of the test, use the same API to update the job and mark it as passed.

Have a look at [job annotation](https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/test-configuration/#job-annotation-with-the-rest-api) setup to get an idea of how this part works. You can then use the [SauceLabs PHP API library](https://github.com/jlipps/sausage) and follow [this example](https://github.com/jlipps/sausage/blob/master/sauce_api_test.php) on how to update job status or write your own utility methods to mimic the behavior.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do the same in Java